# ASP.NET Gridview row names

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datarow

I am using a gridview in an ASP.Net Web Control that I have already assigned columns and will always have 6 rows HC1, HC2, AC1, AC2, AC3, and AC4. I want to initialize the Gridview with the six rows and have the left column be these row names that will stay as readonly even if the DataRow is set to Edit upon the row being clicked on. Is naming the rows in this fashion possible? If not is there a better Tool to use for this or will I have to get creative?

Also if it helps here is the html code creating the gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="blah" AutoGenerateColumns="False" runat="server" Width="540px">
 <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name"></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email"></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Phone"></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Address"></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City"></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="State"></asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Zip"></asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have not written he code behind yet as I am unsure this gridview will do what I need yet

Comment: a DetailsView does this by default.  It's a "grid" of 2 columns where column 1 is the "list" of column names and Column 2 is the associated data.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly and in a helpful fashion but I tried this based on your answer. The details view only allows for two columns so you can't separately have HC1 add first name into one column, last into another and address into another, etc. There is stuff online about using a gridview and detailsview together which seemed like the perfect solution but every time I try it just puts a detailsview under the gridview so I guess I'm a little confused on how to use them together

Comment: you can add an unbound template field, add a label to it and in the Gridview databound event loop through `blah.Columns` and grab the HeaderText from each column to populate the label in the unbound template field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an unbound template field to the gridview and populate with a label:

```
<asp:GridView ID="blah" runat="server" >
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="lblColumnName" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>

    ...   (rest of fields)

  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Then in the Gridview Databound event loop through the column headers and fill columnname for each row

```
Private Sub blah_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles blah.DataBound
  For i As Integer = 1 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1
    lbl = CType(GridView1.Rows(i - 1).FindControl("lblColumnName"), Label)
    lbl.Text = GridView1.Columns(i).HeaderText
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: This works both for labeling the rows and limiting the fields, thank you